# How do I simplify this code?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm really new to vb.net and am looking to make this code less redundant, but I'm not sure how

```
ONE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterOperandStyle = FilterOperandStyle.FilterUIProvider
ONE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow
ONE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIProvider = New SupportDialogs.FilterUIProvider.UltraGridFilterUIProvider()

TWO.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterOperandStyle = FilterOperandStyle.FilterUIProvider
TWO.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow
TWO.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIProvider = New SupportDialogs.FilterUIProvider.UltraGridFilterUIProvider()

THREE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterOperandStyle = FilterOperandStyle.FilterUIProvider
THREE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow
THREE.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIProvider = New SupportDialogs.FilterUIProvider.UltraGridFilterUIProvider()
```

As you can see, the only difference is ONE, TWO and THREE. How do I simplify this without repeating?

Thanks!

Comment: Make it a function...

Comment: Have you tried using a `Select Case`?

Comment: I would use the `with` keyword

Comment: @superPeanut Can you show me how that would be done?

Comment: @David If I used a select case, how would it go through each of the three possibilities?

Comment: @romulus001 I'm really new and am not entirely sure how With works

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this code works, it does not belong on SO.

Comment: @Christopher Hunt have a look on google, I can't explain on here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what is the Type of ONE, TWO and THREE, but you can make a sub :

```
Public Sub DoStuff(Data As YourType)
    Data.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterOperandStyle = FilterOperandStyle.FilterUIProvider
    Data.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow
    Data.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIProvider = New SupportDialogs.FilterUIProvider.UltraGridFilterUIProvider()
End Sub
```

And you call it by doing

```
DoStuff(ONE)
DoStuff(TWO)
DoStuff(THREE)
```

UPDATE (following Andrew Morton's comment)

If you have more than three items, you can run a loop :

```
For each x In { ONE, TWO, THREE }
    DoStuff(x)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SuperPeanut, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @ChristopherHunt If you have more, you could use a loop like `For Each x in {ONE, TWO, THREE}` `DoStuff(x)` `Next`.